# Geocoding custom user meta in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, geocoding, wordpress-geo-mashup

I'm using [User Front End Pro](http://wedevs.com/plugin/wp-user-frontend-pro/) to provide a front end registration form. One line of that is for an address, and I want to use that to display a map of all users with [Geo Mashup](http://wordpress.org/plugins/geo-mashup/).

I have a custom field that saves to user meta called `geocode_address`, I need to then geocode it and output it to two separate fields Latitude and Longitude. I found [this for geocoding custom post data](http://forrst.com/posts/Geocoding_a_custom_field_in_Wordpress-Lbs), and have tried to amend it for user meta, but it is not working, and causes the registration to hang. What have I done wrong?

```
function geocode_address($user_id)
{
$custom_fields = get_user_meta();
if(isset($custom_fields["geocode_address"]) && !empty($custom_fields["geocode_address"][0]))
{
    $resp = wp_remote_get( "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($custom_fields["geocode_address"][0])."&sensor=false" );
    if ( 200 == $resp['response']['code'] ) {
        $body = $resp['body'];
        $data = json_decode($body);
        if($data->status=="OK"){
            $latitude = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
            $longitude = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
            update_user_meta($user_id, "latitude", $latitude);
            update_user_meta($user_id, "longitude", $longitude);
        }
    }
}
}
add_action('update_user_meta', 'geocode_address');
```

As a side note, Geomashup has a function to geocode a custom field, but when I enter "geocode address" it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Can you show a sample value for the field `geocode_address`?

Comment: A sample value would look like: "Vällebergsvägen 7 459 30 Ljungskile"

Answer (score 2):

The action `update_user_meta` takes more arguments and the first one is not the User ID:

```
add_action('update_user_meta', 'geocode_address', 10, 4 );

function geocode_address( $meta_id, $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
    if( 'geocode_address' == $meta_key )
    {
        var_dump( $meta_value );
        die();
    }
}
```

Then, you're using `get_user_meta()` wrong, we need to pass at least the User ID: `get_user_meta($user_id, $key = '', $single = false);`. But I suspect it's not needed in your case.

As for the Geocode API, it returned a correct response when I tested with a random spanish address:

```
$address = "gran via, madrid";
$resp = wp_remote_get( "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address)."&sensor=false" );
```

Comment: I'm struggling to get this to work, I'm afraid (little above my talent grade). I did manage to get the WPUFP to automatically geocode the custom field string, which gets me 80% of the way there but it outputs to a single field as a comma separated value, which led me to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838810/split-comma-separated-values-into-separate-mysql-fields-with-a-wordpress-functio

Comment: I believe your only problem is how to handle the `$meta_value`. The `var_dump` and `die` are the to help you debug and adjust.

Comment: Okay, I have this now. But it still isn't working: http://jsfiddle.net/LRR7y/
(too long for comments) - I'm really not a PHP guy, so I'm struggling with this...